# Robbins Pentagons with Irrational Diagonals

Tags: geometry, number-theory, diophantine-equations

A Robbins pentagon is a cyclic pentagon whose edge lengths and area as all rational numbers.

All known Robbins pentagons have rational *diagonals*, but it has not yet been proven that no Robbins pentagons with irrational diagonals can exist.

Obviously, finding such a pentagon with irrational diagonals would solve this problem. The problem might also be solved  by assuming the existence of a smallest primitive integer Robbins pentagon, and then deducing the existence of a smaller such pentagon with integer side lengths, which would be a proof by contradiction.

Has there been any progress? Have any properties of a hypothetical Robbins pentagon with irrational diagonals been proven?

Comment: Are you aware of this: "Buchholz and MacDougall also showed that, in every Robbins pentagon, either all five of the internal diagonals are rational numbers or none of them are." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robbins_pentagon

Comment: Yes, I am. I have not found any new developments since then.

Comment: I assume that there is a proof for "all are irrational"

Comment: It is printed in R.H.Buchholz,J.A.MacDougall/ Journal of NumberTheory 128 (2008), p. 34

Comment: It seems that it has been proven that such pentagon exist.

Comment: What example exists of a Robbins pentagon with irrational diagonals.